# How to setup an AbstractModule as superclass for other module.php

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a zend framework 2 application and get warnings about duplicated code with phpcpd in my module.php files. The parts

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

and

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

are present in each of them. So it would be a good idea to write a kind of AbstractModule class from which every Module class can inherit these functions.

But I came across two questions:

1) As the autoloading part will be in this super class how can I ensure that this class gets loaded and that this happens also before the child classes.

2) Will the `__DIR__` and `__NAMESPACE__` be set correctly to the right values of the child class when this code is only in the super class

Comment: PhpCPD should simply be ignored for Module-class. You can NOT abstract these things, sorry :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It looks like phpcpd can only exclude directories which automatically exclude subdirectories, or am I wrong? When I use `--exclude module\Application` where the Module.php file is in, the whole Application module is skipped. Can you please provide additional information on this?

Comment: What i mean is: ignore this when evaluating the results of phpcpd. Or what may actually even be better: run phpcpd only on a per-module-basis.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. If you provide this as an answer I can accept it.